# magento - change URL for all links

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, phpmyadmin, e-commerce

it works with

```
http://localhost.magento-store.com/index.php/fashion.html
```

but i need it

```
http://localhost.magento-store.com/fashion.html
```

- the `.htaccess` file includes

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /magento-store.com/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /magento-store.com/index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  ```
- the base URL in database is `http://localhost.magento-store.com/`
- Admin panel:
  SEO-> web server rewrites : yes
  use secure URLs in frontend : yes

what to do more ?

Comment: If the base is just `/`, why are you setting the base to the folder `/magento-store.com/`?

Comment: @JonLin there is sub-folder under `public_html` folder. it was `/` before but the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `.htaccess` file being applied by the server? You can test this by introducing a syntax error in the `.htaccess` file and seeing if your server returns a `500 Internal Server Error`. If you don't get an error, then your `.htaccess` file isn't being applied. This is usually due to an `AllowOverride` directive in your server configuration. Try adding `AllowOverride All` for your DocumentRoot directory. Keep in mind that this has to be done in the server configuration, so don't put it in `.htaccess`.

With that said, remove the `RewriteBase` directive (or set it to `/` instead of `/magento-store.com/`), and remove the `/magento-store.com/` from the `RewriteRule` directive. If `http://localhost.magento-store.com/index.php/` works fine, then your `DocumentRoot` must be the same directory as the `index.php` file, so you don't want to specify a directory to the `index.php` file.

For reference, here's a stripped down version of Magento's sample .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` file being applied by the server? You can test this by introducing a syntax error in the `.htaccess` file and seeing if your server returns a `500 Internal Server Error`. If you don't get an error, then your `.htaccess` file isn't being applied. This is usually due to an `AllowOverride` directive in your server configuration. Try adding `AllowOverride All` for your `DocumentRoot` directory. Keep in mind that this has to be done in the server configuration, so don't put it in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thank you, you can edit your answer to accept it as a solution

Comment: Great, I'm glad we were able to resolve it. I've edited my answer to include the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your apache server **rewrite_module** enable or not.